# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema with Sage eBusiness Web Services

Tags: web, wsdl

I have reviewed other questions with this SOAP error - this seems different.
We are trying to run an order.php to pass test data to a Sage MAS 90/IIS server with eBusiness Web Services installed. The wsdl entry point is here:
https://distro.cac.org/ebusinesswebservices/masbasicwsdl.svc?wsdl

The test file is here:
http://cac.org/order.php

It's a Joomla 2.5.6 site running Virtuemart 2.0.10 - server is running php 5.3.10, Apache 2.2 with nginx serving static assets. SOAP is installed. 
Thanks in advance for any ideas/help!
-Alan